# Difference between EventArrivedEventHandler and EventHandler?

Tags: c#, event-handling, anonymous-methods

I tried to create a USB controller class and just tried to expose my internal `EventArrivedEventHandler` from `ManagementEventWatcher` to allow the consumer to do something if a USB is detected.

I had expected to be able to cast the EventArrivedEventHandler  to a EventHandler, as they are all just delegates... but apparently not.

Is there a reason why this is not possible?

EDIT: I have found an approach that lets me do what I wanted very cleanly.

```
_watcher.EventArrived += (sender, eventArgs) => DeviceDetected?.Invoke(null, null);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why this is not possible is that `EventArraivedEventHandler` and `EventHandler` have different signatures. As you can see, the `EventArrivedEventHandler` take as second argument `EventArrivedEventArgs` and not `EventArgs` as `EventHandler` does.

```
public delegate void EventArrivedEventHandler(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
```

In theory it should be possible to cast this to an `EventHandler<EventArrivedEventArgs>`.

Visit the MSDN Page for [EventArivedEventHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.eventarrivedeventhandler(v=vs.110).aspx) and [EventArrivedEventArgs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.eventarrivedeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx) for further details about this issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
public event EventHandler DriveDetected;

private void workaround(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
{
    DriveDetected?.Invoke(sender, e as EventArgs);
}

watcher.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(workaround);
```

Based on your post. Cheers.